# Does sorting benefit insert in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a benefit of sorting the data in `*.dat` file based on INDEXED column before pushing them to the STAGING table in SQL Server?

Ok, the scenerio is :

I have a `STAGING` table with 40 columns and indexes on 5 columns. I need to push data from a file that contains 15 million rows into the `STAGING` table.

The approach I have followed is:

- First, DISABLE the INDEXES
- Second, push the data from file to STAGING table
- Third, REBUILD INDEXES OFFLINE

Now I need to understand if I will sort the data in the file based on column that is indexed will it benefit in any way :

1. IN INSERT
2. IN INDEX REBUILD.

Comment: [Race your hourses.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Sorting by a clustered index would probably give the best performance in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

General answer: No!

15 million rows is quite a lot... It depends on how you are querying / filtering / sorting your data and it depends on the quality of your data:

- Does your table have a clustered key (Are you aware of the difference between a clustered and a non-clustered index)?
- Is there a *one-column* key candidate which is implicitly sorted (like `IDENTITIY`)?
- Will the table see a lot of delets / inserts in future?

SQL-Server does not know any implicit sorting.

Only one case comes to my mind: If there is an active clustered index and you insert your data in a pre-sorted way, the rows should be added at the end and your index will not be fragmented and therefore will not need a rebuild at the end.

If you remove your indexes and insert your data, insertion should be faster, but you'll need a lot of work to get a clustered key in the right physical order at the end.

Many big tables define a **non-clustered** primary key and no clustered key at all...

My suggestion

- remove all non-clustered indexes
- If your table has an implicitly sorted PK and new rows are sorted to the end automatically, you should define this as clustered key and do the inserts pre-sorted.
- If the above does not apply, you should do your inserts without any index and create the indexes after the insert operation.